# How do I get Robotframework (in Eclipse) to respond to terminal prompt

Tags: eclipse, usb, robotframework

I'm currently running Robotframework in Eclipse on Windows 10 OS. I'm using an external python library that allows students and teachers to use this extracted library to connect to our hardware devices. I'm automating the extractions from the main site package made by our developers. If more than one device is plugged into the USB ports on the PC, then the code does the following:

x = input("Select one device:")

selected = int(x)

This causes a terminal prompt so the user has to type in a 0, or 1 for example, then hit the ENTER key. User response will allow the code to further process a connect to the selected device. Note, this prompt is not a GUI. So when I run Robotframework, it will execute the steps up to the point where it's prompting.

It seems like this should be pretty easy, but I can't seem to figure it out. Since you're inside a piece of code that's waiting for input, how do you make RobotFramework do something with it?

Edit: It occurs to me that maybe there's a way to execute a delayed Robotframework step that starts an external python command after a specified time, to throw a '0' and a RETURN key response. I had a python file made from an import of pynput.py library which appears to work from the command line execution (prints a 0, or a 1, and a return line feed). There's gotta be an easier way I'd think, but I don't know what it is.

Edit: Can I run a keyword from a listener that watches for the command prompt and the keyword runs another python file to feed the prompt? If I get this to work, then all I have to do is leave the devices on the USB port (or hub for that matter), and select the devices I want to do further testing on. Our devices are supported Blooth tooth as well but I need to run both USB and BLE tests to verify our Python extractions the teachers and students can use.

Edit: The other option is to use a software programmable hub and select the USB with a specific device on it, but I'm trying to avoid that.

Answer (score 2):

OK, I solved it using Robotframework background process. I wrote a small python file that gets executed from the process. It has a 5 second timer (more than I need) and then Robotframework runs the next Test Case step. The Python file then does some keyboard presses, selecting the port and an ENTER key which goes out to the console (feeding the input prompt). It connects the sensor.

So in my Robotframework Test Case I do the following:

```
*** Test Case ***
smoke_test
    Start process .   Python .   usbportselect
    open usb
```

The Python program called from the process looks like this:

```
import time
import pynput
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller
keyboard = Controller()

def choose_usb(portvalue)
    keyboard.press(portvalue)
    keyboard.release(portvalue)
    keyboard.press(Key.enter)
    keyboard.release(Key.enter)

time.sleep(5)
choose_usb('0')
```

Note: I'm pretty sure this won't fix all the problems with using processes, but it's at least a start and a way to feed input to a prompt resulted from a future Test Case step